# Rails send_data timeout issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To achieve export to excel, I use RubyXL to create a workbook based on queried result, and use send_data to download. The code is like:

```
  workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
  # Fill workbook here 
  send_data workbook.stream.string, filename: "myrpeort.xlsx", disposition: 'attachment'
```

It works well when there are not too much data, but when the data size increases, for example the saved excel file exceeds 3M, the download fails in browser with following message:
Network Error (tcp_error)

> A communication error occurred: ""
>   The Web Server may be down, too
>   busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to
>   requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Seems it is not related to server timeout setting, I even changed the timeout in unicorn to 6000 (100 minutes), it still did not work...

Could you throw me some light on how to solve the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have nginx before unicorn?

Comment: In my local dev environment, there is no Nginx...